# VirtualBox webserver not accessbile on host browser

Tags: virtualbox, port-forwarding, webserver, bridge

I setup and installed a CentOS6 webserver on a virtualbox.

Already setup port-forwarding of port 4444 to 80 so that I can access it and even disabled Win7 firewall.

I think that probably the problem is in apache `httpd` so I install `lynx` and I can view the test.html I created. But I can't access it in the host browser.

`ifconfig` says the guest ip is `10.0.2.15` so when I try to access it in my web browser on i type : `http://10.0.2.15:4444`

I don't know what's wrong with my setup

EDIT:
`127.0.0.1:4444` doesn't work either

EDIT:
Switched network type to bridged networking, still has windows firewall disabled, removed port-forwarding setting on virtualbox and I still could not access the web server. :(

Comment: If you are portforwarding+NAT rather than using bridged networking, you would be accessing this from the host on http://127.0.0.1:4444

Comment: @Paul 127.0.0.1:4444 still doesn't work

Comment: It sounds like the Linux server is running on 80 and you're forwarding that to 4444 on the Windows host so you can access from other machines? If so, 10.0.2.15:80 on the host machine should work, and host-machine-LAN-IP:4444 should work elsewhere on your physical network. Any particular reason for not using bridged networking?

Comment: @Vickash 10.0.2.15:80 doesn't work either. I just simply want to access the web server on my host PC. I have now switched to bridged networking. Guest OS has internet, but still could not access it.

Comment: If you have switched to bridged networking, then the IP address on the server should be different, and now reside in the same subnet as your host (if it did prior to the switch, then that was probably the reason it didn't work - natted networks are on their own subnet).  Can you ping it?

Comment: @Paul yes, the IP is different and I can `ping` to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the cause. Apparently, CentOS 6 `iptables` block httpd port 80 outside by default.