# Virtualbox port forwarding not accessible from browser

Tags: virtualbox, port-forwarding

I got similar case with this one [VirtualBox webserver not accessbile on host browser](https://superuser.com/questions/444711/virtualbox-webserver-not-accessbile-on-host-browser)

My case is I can easily forward the ssh port. But for my rails development server on guest OS, WEBrick, which by default running on port 3000 is not accessible from host's browser on localhost:9030. I have tried to change the port both in guest and host but no difference. I wonder why the port forwarding doesn't work from browser.

Also, I've disabled firewall on host's OS and check `iptables -L -n` on guest buy didn't see any blocked port.

Comment: Maybe the server is accepting connections only from localhost?

Comment: @gronostaj I don't think so. I've put the server to run on `0.0.0.0:3000`

Comment: @gronostaj aaand it is working after I restart everything. thx mate!

Comment: It sounds good!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following rule from your guest OS

say,
Guest OS IP -10.0.0.132

Host IP -10.0.0.133

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT -d 10.0.0.132 -p tcp --dport 3000 --to 10.0.0.133
```

Also verify the connection from your host server by telnet(ing)on the port 3000 to your guest OS.

Comment: so if a VM runs linux then iptables can do the forwarding instead of virtualbox vm settings?